# "Execute as self" vs cross database views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 2016. There's a view in the database `A` that makes a selection from a table in another database, `B`:

```
use A
go
create view TheView as
select * from B.dbo.SomeTable
```

I have dbo access to the `B` database, and I can query the view all I want:

```
select * from TheView -- Works as expected
```

Now I've created a procedure with `EXECUTE AS SELF` clause, hoping it will execute as me:

```
use A
go
create proc dbo.f
with execute as self
as
select * from TheView
```

When I run it, I get the following:

> The server principal "ACME\seva" is not able to access the database "B" under the current security context.

If I remove the `execute as` clause, the procedure runs as expected.

I'm connecting with a Windows domain account, using integrated security.

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-cross-database-access-in-sql-server

Comment: But I *am* listed as a user in the other database.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, you need check if you have enabed Cross-Database Access in the current DB, by default, it's off. Please see the link from lad2025

Comment: Enabled for the database where the view and the SP are. Same error message. Can't do that for the other database, where the table is.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev So as always there is something more. Please describe your situation (maybe some picture). Based on prev comment I see it like this: DB1 (stored procedure) DB2 (view) DB3 (table referenced by view). Are linked server also involved?

Comment: Edited. There are two databases involved.

Comment: If by "passthrough auth" you mean integrated security AKA a Windows domain account, then yes, I'm connecting as one of those. There are no linked servers involved, it's all on one server.

Answer (score 3):

`EXECUTE AS` impersonation is sandboxed to the current database unless the database is set to [`TRUSTWORTHY`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2183687/guidelines-for-using-the-trustworthy-database-setting-in-sql-server). Rather than turning on the TRUSTWORTHY database option, consider a less heavy-handed approach to extending security across databases. Methods to provide a non-privileged user permissions across databases include:

**DB_CHAINING:**

[`DB_CHAINING ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-cross-database-access-in-sql-server) allows standard intra-database ownership chaining to extend across databases so that permissions on indirectly accessed objects are not required. Users need only execute permissions on your `dbo.f` stored procedure as long as the ownership chaining is unbroken. Note that users will still to be a user in database B but no object permissions need be granted. For example:

```
ALTER DATABASE A SET DB_CHAINING ON;
ALTER DATABASE B SET DB_CHAINING ON;
```

The implication with DB_CHAINING and dbo-owned objects is that both database `A` and `B` must be owned by the same login in order to maintain an unbroken ownership chain for the `dbo` user. The database owner(s) can be changed using ALTER AUTHORIZATION if needed:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::A to DatabaseOwnerLogin;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::B to DatabaseOwnerLogin;
```

**Module Signing:**

[Module signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/signing-stored-procedures-in-sql-server) allows one to add additional permissions to a module via a certificate user. Create a certificate, create a user from the certificate, grant the certificate user the needed permissions, and then sign the stored procedure with the certificate. Below is sample code gleaned from [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html).

An advantage of module signing over DB_CHAINING is that the calling user does not need to have be a user in database B because the cert user provides the security context. Be aware that the proc will need to be re-signed if it is later altered.

```
USE B;
-- create certifciate, cert user, and grant needed permissions
CREATE CERTIFICATE cross_database_cert
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'All you need is love'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'For cross-database access';
CREATE USER cross_database_cert FROM CERTIFICATE cross_database_cert;
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.SomeTable TO cross_database_cert;
GO
-- Copy cert to database A
DECLARE @cert_id int = cert_id('cross_database_cert')
DECLARE @public_key  varbinary(MAX) = certencoded(@cert_id),
        @private_key varbinary(MAX) =
           certprivatekey(@cert_id,
              'All you need is love',
              'All you need is love')

SELECT @cert_id, @public_key, @private_key

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) =
      'CREATE CERTIFICATE cross_database_cert
       FROM  BINARY = ' + convert(varchar(MAX), @public_key, 1) + '
       WITH PRIVATE KEY (BINARY = ' +
          convert(varchar(MAX), @private_key, 1) + ',
          DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''All you need is love'',
          ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''All you need is love'')'

EXEC A.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
GO
ALTER CERTIFICATE cross_database_cert REMOVE PRIVATE KEY;
GO
USE A;
GO
--sign proc with certificate
ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.f BY CERTIFICATE cross_database_cert
   WITH PASSWORD = 'All you need is love';
GO
ALTER CERTIFICATE cross_database_cert REMOVE PRIVATE KEY;
GO
```